# como posicionar um triangulo criado com css?

Tags: html, css

Como posso posicionar uma div que cria um triangulo ao lado de um item do meu menu?

```
<div class="triangulo">
</div>

.triangulo{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17.5px 30.3px 17.5px 0;
    border-color: transparent gray transparent transparent;
}
```

Preciso posicionar ele ao lado do icone da dashboard.

```
<div class="sidenavprincipal z-depth-1">
    <div id="avatar"></div>

    <div id="containerIconesLateral" class="container">

        <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12 alinhaColuna">
                    <svg class="svgIconeMenu" style="width:40px;height:40px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill="rgb(161,196,66)" d="M19,5V7H15V5H19M9,5V11H5V5H9M19,13V19H15V13H19M9,17V19H5V17H9M21,3H13V9H21V3M11,3H3V13H11V3M21,11H13V21H21V11M11,15H3V21H11V15Z" />
                    </svg>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                    <span class="tipografiaDescricaoIcone">Dashboard</span>
                </div>

        </div>
```

[image: Resultado esperado]

consegui colocando como position absolute e usando margem até chegar no meu destino, porém acredito que essa não é a forma correta de se fazer.

Comment: Cara vc está usando Bootstrap?? Qual versão?

Comment: material design bootstrap, ultima versão

Comment: Tentei dessa forma: #colDash::BEFORE {
    content: ".";
    width: 0;
    margin: -30%;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17.5px 30.3px 17.5px 0;
    border-color: transparent #026FBD transparent transparent;
    z-index: 9;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 62%;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

1-) Na marcação HTML coloque o `<div class="triangulo"></div>` logo após a `tag` de fechamento da `SVG` `</svg>`, conforme mostrado a seguir:

```
<div class="col-12 alinhaColuna">
   <svg class="svgIconeMenu" style="width:40px;height:40px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <path fill="rgb(161,196,66)" d="M19,5V7H15V5H19M9,5V11H5V5H9M19,13V19H15V13H19M9... />
   </svg>
   <div class="triangulo"></div>
</div>
```

2-) Altere a regra CSS para:

```
.triangulo{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 18px 30px 18px 0;
  border-color: transparent gray transparent transparent;
}
```

> **Nota:** Se você definir `border-width: 20px 30px 20px 0;` não precisará da declaração `margin-bottom: 2px;`, isso porque seu `SVG` tem altura `40px` e o triângulo terá a mesma altura do `SVG`, alinhando automaticamente na vertical.